# Table aliasing to a column allows direct access to the column with same name?

Tags: postgresql

I stumbled upon sqlite's query sudoku query `https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html` and noticed they used the following syntax:

```
[other stuff...]
            SELECT 1
              FROM digits AS lp
             WHERE z.z = substr(s, ((ind-1)/9)*9 + lp, 1)
[...more stuff]
```

where `digits` is a temporary table defined earlier: `digits(z text, lp int)`. However, the expression `((ind-1/9)*9 + lp` apparently is valid syntax, but I thought it was not possible to add directly on a table?

---

Here I made a reproducible example (with postgres) that illustrates what works and what doesn't work:

```
-- fails: no table alias
with digits(d, s) as (values (1, '1'))
select * from digits where digits >= 1;

-- works: alias to d
with digits(d, s) as (values (1, '1'))
select * from digits as d where d >= 1;

-- fails: alias to foo
with digits(d, s) as (values (1, '1'))
select * from digits as foo where foo >= 1;

-- works: alias to foo, but treat as a record
with digits(d, s) as (values (1, '1'))
select * from digits as foo where foo.d >= 1;
```

What is going on here? And where can I read more about this? It seems to be part of the sql standard?

Comment: `lp` is a column of the table `digits`, isn't it?

Comment: "Table aliasing to a column" in the title doesn't seem to make sense. A table alias is an alias for a table, not for a column. Also, why pick up queries from the SQLite manual to run them in Postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column names overrule table names. An unqualified identifier (a "simple name") can only resolve to the row type of a table expression in scope when no matching column is in scope. In [your given example](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html), there is a column `digits.lp`, just like there is a column `digits.d` in your examples. All as expected.

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-USAGE)

> [...] simple names are matched to column names before table names

Table-qualify columns to remove any ambiguity. The given example is really just sloppy and inconsistent in that regard, table-qualifying some columns, but not others. It would not have mislead you if it was explicit like that:

```
WITH RECURSIVE ...
  digits(z, lp) AS (  -- !
     ...
  ),
  x(s, ind) AS (
    SELECT ...
    FROM x, digits AS z
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
           FROM digits AS lp
          WHERE z.z = substr(s, ((ind-1)/9)*9 + lp.lp, 1)  -- !
          AND   ...
      )
)
...
```

Comment: See [this source comment](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/parser/parse_expr.c;h=346fd272b6d17ad3eda86b3ff0a2041ca59763b9;hb=HEAD#l579).

Answer (score 0):

It's not adding to the table.  You can add fields with values defined in the query itself.  They are just part of the result, they are not added to the table.